# How to declare DLL in user32.dll (aka stdcall?) fashion?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll, compiler-construction

I have a third party application that allows you to call C functions from DLL files. Provided sample to this app shows you can call MessageBoxW from user32.dll. It also allows you to call C functions from your DLL files.

I've did a DLL from a file.h file like this:

```
_declspec (dllexport) void example(int);
```

and file.c like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file.h"

_declspec (dllexport) void example(int s1)
{
    printf("dsa");    
}
```

And compile it with C/C++ Compiler Version 15 from Windows SDK like this:

```
cl file.c /DLL /LD
```

And i get proper compilation with DLL file. In DLL functions examiner I see my function. I drop this file into System32 folder and call it from this third party application.

Application finds the file, but is unable to find the function.

I think the cause of the problem is that i declare (or compile) my DLL in other fashion/way/standard that Windows libraries (like user32.dll) because user32.dll works fine.

I've found that the third party app uses this kind of calling functions in DLL:

> winapi_abi Used for calling Windows system functions. These are
>   declared as stdcall on Windows, but do not have mangled names.

So my question is: how to prepare and compile DLL file in the user32.dll fashion (stdcall?) so it will work with third party app?

Comment: I don't get why you are even bothering with all that "_declspec (dllexport)" crap. Why not just remove it; and compile and link it normally? That is, what made you take on this mindless challenge?

Comment: @Pete Like i wrote it's third party app and i don't have much choice about how it calls functions so you know.... I've tried this with declspec but it's not working.

Comment: And __stdcall function name is still mangled when exported.  Leading underscore and trailing @x, like _example@4.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports to see that.  Renaming the export to plain "export" requires a .def file.

Comment: @tomaszs and Hans -- sorry, I didn't see the reason. thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Hans Yes, it's exactly what i see in dumpbin now. I've added EXPORTS example in DEF file and did /DEF:simple.def but still see _example@4 in dumpbin.exe. What to do now?

Comment: If the pdb is available, dumpbin may show the original decorated name as well as the exported name. Check the actual exported name, not just "anything in the dumpbin output that contains the word 'example'." If the actual exported name is _example@4 then my guess is that you didn't rebuild clean.

Comment: Thanks, i figured that i need to remove stdcall thanks!

Comment: Don't remove `__stdcall`. Asside from affecting export names, it also dictates how the compiler manages function parameters and the call stack. A function and its caller must match in that regard or bad things happen (corrupted memory, crashes, etc). Besides, the winapi_abi specifically says to use `__stdcall`. It is a standardized calling convention that just about every compiler supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall example(int);
```

And the same in the implementation, of course.

If you look into `windows.h` and friends you'll see:

```
#define WINUSERAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#define WINAPI __stdcall
```

And then:

```
WINUSERAPI int WINAPI MessageBoxW(HWND,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,UINT);
```

But if you just define a few functions there is no need for the macros.

Comment: I did it in this fasion and still it does not work. Is there some other things there? or maybe DLLs are compiled other way in windows?

Comment: Actually, WINUSERAPI is not defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` because that exports decorated names. There isn't much information about what the third party program expects, but I'm guessing that it does a `GetProcAddress` on the name you provide, so you need to build your DLL with an EXPORTS section that gives the exact name you want to export.

Comment: @Raymond I think it can be the issue. I added to DEF file EXPORTS example but when i do dumbin /EXPORTS file.dll i see name _example@4. What i do wrong? I need only this one function.

Comment: ive added solution in my answer, it's basically what you wrote +removing __stdcall and adding def file.

Answer (score 1):

Include a .def file to defeat stdcall name decoration. Then you can get rid of the __declspec(dllexport) clutter.

Comment: I've tried this approach. I've added EXPORTS example @1 to DEF and /DEF:file.def in compilation parameters and removed declspec from file.h and file.c files but than after dumpbin /EXPORTS file.dll i don't see any more function (before removing _declspec i've seen _example@4). What i do wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ive put the solution together in my answer, but your did help me a lot thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying any calling convention in your function declaration, so the compiiler will default to `__cdecl`, which decorates the exported name.  Also, if you compile in C++ instead of C, additional decorating occurs as well.  You need to do something like the following in your code to get around all of that:

file.h:

```
#ifndef fileH
#define fileH

#ifdef _BUILDING_DLL_
#define MYEXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define MYEXPORT __declspec (dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

MYEXPORT void __stdcall example(int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

file.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _BUILDING_DLL_
#include "file.h"

void __stdcall example(int s1)
{
   printf("dsa");
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand, i do C DLL, not C++ and build DLL so BUILDING_DLL is true and extern part is here not used so... what is the difference between this and my code? Sorry if i lost something can you write it? When i use my code in dumprep i have name _example@4 - its not good i suppose...

Comment: ive added solution. It was what you wrote + addng export file and removing stdcall. Thanks!

Comment: Adding the .def file is fine, but removing `__stdcall` is the wrong thing to do. See other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. The solution was to add def file with exports, include it in compiler by /DEF:file.def, use Remy version (without #define _BUILDING...) and remove _stdcall.

Comment: If you remove `stdcall` then you'll get `cdecl`. But you said you needed `stdcall`.

Comment: `stdcall` is more than just name mangling. If the docs say so, you should have it, and moreover, rename the symbols if needed.

Comment: The purpose of `_BUILDING_DLL_` is to allow the same .h file to be used in both the DLL and other projects that want to statically link to the DLL functions. Since only the DLL would declare `_BUILDING_DLL_`, the .h file would mark the functions for exporting, while other projects would mark them for importing instead.